# jQuery variable scope within each

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, scope, each

I am trying to build an array containing all the values of every form element. The alert works just find, but on console.log data is empty, am I failing to understand how scoping in javascript works?

```
  var data = new Array();
  $("#page2 input").each(function(index) {
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
      data[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
  });
```

Many thanks for your time,

Comment: Far more efficient to write: `this.id` and `this.value`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing to know is that an `Array` in JavaScript can only ever have positive integer indexes (which are really treated as strings).

When you assign a string to the key, you are assigning properties to an `Object`.

You probably want something like this...

```
var data = {};
$("#page2 input").each(function() {
   data[this.id] = this.value;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/JXE2j/).

If you wanted just the `id` attributes.

```
var data = $("#page2 input").map(function() { 
               return this.id;
           }).get();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/zqZsb/).

Comment: Thanks, especially for the second part, looks interesting! I've got to stop programming two languages at once (PHP/Javascript), lead to this confusion!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to make an *object* (`new Object()` or `{ }`), not an array.

Answer (score 1):

The scope is correct. If the console is not displaying entires in the Array, then I'm guessing that your ID attributes are not numeric.

Doesn't meant that the data isn't there. Just means that the console chooses to only display the numeric indices.

Consider the following input into Chrome's console:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr['test'] = 'test';

arr;  // []
arr.test;  // 'test'
```

While it is valid JavaScript to give a non numeric property to an Array, in *most* cases it is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was:

> ...all the values of every form element...

but your selector was only for input elements in one particular form. Presuming that you actually wanted the values of all the controls in a form, then the following POJS may suit:

```
function getFormValues(formId) {
  var data = {};
  var form = document.getElementById(formId);

  if (form) {
    var control, controls = form.elements;

    if (controls) {
      var i = controls.length;

      while (i--) {
        control = controls[i];
        data[control.id] = control.value;
      }
    }
  } 
  return data;
}
```

Presuming that every control has an ID, which is not a requirement. If some controls don't have an id, you might want to use the name property instead, so:

```
        data[control.id || control.name] = control.value;
```

In some cases, your controls may not have an id or a name (e.g. controls that are needed for the form but whose values are not to be submitted, such as submit and reset buttons) so:

```
        var idOrName = control.id || control.name;
        if (idOrName) {
          data[idOrName] = control.value;
        }
```

You may also need to deal with controls having the same name, since the value of whichever one is accessed last will replace the value of previous same-named controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the input id as a key what you're creating is an Object, not an Array.

```
var data = new Object();
```